# How to use Heremaps charge points API

Tags: heremaps

When trying to access:

```
https://ev-v2.cit.cc.api.here.com/ev/stations.json
?prox=52.516667,13.383333,5000
&connectortype=31&apiKey={myapikeyhere}
```

I keep getting response:

```
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
```

I'm on Freemium plan, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: did you ever find out what went wrong?